# Prevent Sublime Text from overwriting .sublime-project

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Running Sublime Text 3 with the [Anaconda IDE package](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) on Mac OS X, it appears that when I edit the `.sublime-project` file, for some reason some of the changes will be removed after some time.

Any ideas how to prevent this?

**Before**

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "name": "Anaconda Python Builder",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "shell_cmd": "~/anaconda/envs/test/bin/python -u \"$file\"",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "/Users/nyx/test"
            }
        }
    ],
```

**After**

*`env` setting is removed. Not sure what triggers this*

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "name": "Anaconda Python Builder",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "shell_cmd": "~/anaconda/envs/test/bin/python -u \"$file\"",
        }
    ],
```

Comment: The whole build_systems part of the project file is regularly re-written to the above even if its removed completely.

Comment: It is infuriating that Anaconda (or anyone else for that matter) rewrites project files.  That is exactly what we try to avoid when we use Sublime instead of IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

If it's having a problem with the 'env' tag and resetting it, can you try [extra_paths](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/#toc_5)?

```
{
    "settings": {
        "extra_paths":
        [
            "/Users/nyx/test"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nyxynyx This is the correct answer. The "Anaconda Python Builder" is spot-checked by the plugin on occasion and rewritten (for whatever reason), so if you want to customize it you'll need to write your own. For extending Anaconda's path, `"extra_paths"` is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation MattDMo.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229009/anaconda-ignoring-extra-paths-in-sublime-text-settings#comment63910722_38229009 `extra_paths` is for linting not for building, which is what @Nyxynyx was asking about.