# Set PYTHONPATH in Sublime 3

Tags: python, pythonpath

I'm using Sublime editor for writing Python programs, with the Anaconda plugin.

I have a Python project which relies on some custom python lib I wrote in another directory.

I first modified the MyProject.sublime-project file in the build_systems section, it seemed to work but after some time, the sublime-project file is automaticcally overwritten.

I then found that the right way to do it is to add a settings/extra_paths section (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643793/prevent-sublime-text-from-overwriting-sublime-project)) and my sublime-project file looks like this :

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "name": "Anaconda Python Builder",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "shell_cmd": "\"python\" -u \"$file\""
        }
    ],
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": 
    {
        "extra_paths":
        [
            "C:\\path\\to\\my_lib"
        ]
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Not only my libs import aren't found by the Python interpreter, but if I type :

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

I can't see my directory listed.

What am I doing wrong ?